# Problem using map method with react (posts.map is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

i'm having an error while trying to map an array (code below). The error i'm receiving is :  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: posts.map is not a function.
I have compared it to one of my old project, and it worked perfectly on the older one. Thanks in advance

```
const MainContent = () => {
  
  const openModal = () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
  };

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const getPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/post/');
    const posts = await response.json();
    setPosts(posts);
    console.log(posts)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="main-content-section">
      <button className="button post-btn" onClick={openModal}>
        Créer un nouveau post
      </button>
      <ModalPost style={{ display: "none" }} />
      <div className="post-container">
        {posts.map((post) => {
          const { id, title, content, author } = post;
          return (
            <div className="post-content" key={id}>
              <div className="post-content__user-info">
                <div className="post-content__photo-container">
                   
                </div>
                <div className="post-content__name">
                  <h3>{author}</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="post-content__content">
                <h3>{title}</h3>
                <p>{content}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="post-content__like-box">
                <BiHeart className="like-heart like" size={26} />
                <RiDislikeLine className="dislike-heart dislike" size={26} />
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })} 
      </div>

    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try to define your getPosts functions inside your useEffect hook itself. Also, log the value of posts before setting posts.

Comment: Is "posts" an array? We can't see the response.

Comment: Important to note that when you do console.log(posts) you are referring to the internal posts variable(const) not the state variable

Comment: Just add `if` statement before mapping `post` array. The reason is that posts array does not get data immediately causing map function to fail. `if` condition will wait until posts array actually contains data
`
{
   (posts && posts.length > 0) ?
       posts.map((post) => {}
       : (<p> loading... </p>)
}

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `if` statement before mapping `post` array. The reason is that posts array does not get data immediately causing map function to fail. `if` condition will wait until posts array actually contains data

```
{
   (posts && posts.length > 0) ?
       (posts.map((post) => {})
       : (<p> loading... </p>)
}
```

Comment: this answer will most likely work, but does not actually explain the issue. it's perfectly fine to call `.map()` on an empty array.

Comment: It is fine to call `.map()` on empty array. But this action will effect UX of this page. User won't be able to figure out why there is nothing on page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const getPosts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/post/');
    const posts = await response.json();
    setPosts(posts);
    console.log(posts)
  }
```

Here, the result of response.json() is going to be an object, and not an array. Probably, you have to look inside the object and find the posts array.